# How to set class provider type for whole methods in MyBatis mapper interface

Tags: sql, jpa, interface, annotations, mybatis

I have interface personMapper and methods like this.

```
public interface EmployeeMapper {

    @SelectProvider(type = EmployeeMapperImpl.class, method = "getAll")
    List<Employee> getAll();

//similar methods

}
```

and also i have one class for whole interface

```
public class EmployeeMapperImpl{


    public String getAll() {
        return new SQL().
                SELECT("*").
                FROM(Employee.class.getSimpleName()).toString();
    }

}
```

I would like to know if it is possible, how to mark interface associated with the defined class to get rid of writing "type=EmployeeMapperImpl" in every method? And completely get rid of writing method = "getAll" because its' titles are the same in class and in interface. I would like to get something like that

```
@ProviderForAllMethods("EmployeeMapperImpl")
  public interface EmployeeMapper {

        //and methods are associeted by their names(the same in class and constructor)
        List<Employee> getAll();

    //similar methods

    }
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Omitting `method` is possible if you are using MyBatis 3.5.1 or later.
- Omitting `type` is not possible at the moment (current latest is 3.5.4).
- Annotating the mapper interface itself would be technically difficult.

To omit `method`, your SQL provider class needs to implement [`ProviderMethodResolver`](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/edc7be7e0c5f05efea0230bf3b45e58c9b4d5b95/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/builder/annotation/ProviderMethodResolver.java) interface.
The default implementation, as you expect, searches a provider method with the same name as the interface method.

```java
public class EmployeeMapperImpl implements ProviderMethodResolver {
```

Also we made the `type` attribute of SQL provider annotations as an alias to `value` in version 3.5.2, so your mapper method can be a little bit simpler.

```java
public interface EmployeeMapper {
  @SelectProvider(EmployeeMapperImpl.class)
  List<Employee> getAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if i want to make like this, without using additional class. How can i fix the "element value must be a constant value". I would like to shrink this code like this ``String getAll = new SQL().
            SELECT("*").
            FROM(Employee.class.getSimpleName()).toString();
    @Select(getAll)
    List<Employee> getAll();

Comment: What do you mean by 'additional class'? There are two classes in your question (i.e. `EmployeeMapper` and `EmployeeMapperImpl`) and my answer requires no other classes. Also there is no `@Select` in your question, is that a new question?

Comment: I mean without using a EmployeeMapperImpl. Just only interface with @Select annotation method and SQL().SELECT("*").FROM(Employee.class.getSimpleName()).toString() as a parameter. I am considering different options)

Comment: Ah, that is not possible. Java does not allow it. Just FYI, the provider class can be nested inside the mapper interface, so you can edit the SQL generation code in the same file if that helps.

Comment: Thats working for me @Select("select * from employee")   List<Employee> getAll(); But im' trying to make a dynamic sql expresssion to exclude possible runtime errors

Comment: That seems like a different question and I have no idea how that is possible. :)

Comment: Thanks, but can u advice me which ways in which situations i must use? Using @Select annotation with query as a parameter, use class mapperImpl with SQL() builder and  SelectProvider annotation, or making SelectStatementProvider in class and also using SelectProvider annotation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210068/discussion-between-ave-and-vytsalo).